# How to write a Makefile for LEDE to install my new driver?

Tags: openwrt

I have written a Makefile to compile my driver in LEDE.The problem was the xxx.ko file is available in /lib/modules/`uname -r`/ directory but that module is no install from the boot.So can you help me to rewrite my Makefile to bring my driver installed from the boot.I have attached my Makefile here.

```
define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C "$(LINUX_DIR)" $(MAKE_OPTS) modules
endef

define Package/kmod-ax88772/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/etc/init.d
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/lib/modules/$(LINUX_VERSION) 
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/sbin
endef
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Once when we give the modprobe xxx.ko it is getting install but I don't want this,that should install from the boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autoload in your makefile, like

> AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoLoad,30, moduleName)

Comment: Thank you, for your reply.But for me $(call AutoLoad,30,moduleName) is not working.Rather $(call AutoProbe,moduleName) is only working.